# Drop Down Styles Issue angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootstrap-multiselect

I am facing serious issues with drop down its design get weird when populating the drop down when using this chunk of html I am getting this design:

**index.html**

```
 <select id="chkveg" ng-model="ArrangeSurveyCtrl.sections"  ng-options="item
        as item.section for item in ArrangeSurveyCtrl.sections" multiple="multiple">
```

I tried with  static value and it worked perfect:
[image]

**index.html**

```
                   <option value="AJ">AJ</option>

                    <option value="Valuation">Valuation</option>
                   <option value="Comps">Comps</option>
```

[image]

**index.js**

```
   $(function() {

            $('#chkveg').multiselect({

                includeSelectAllOption: true

            });
            $('#btnget').click(function() {

                alert($('#chkveg').val());

            })
        });
 getAllSections();
        function getAllSections() {
            ArrangeSurveyService.getAllSections().
            then(function(result) {
                var serverData = result.data;

                if (serverData.success) {
                    if(serverData) {
                        vm.sections = serverData.result;
                        console.log(vm.sections);

                    }
                }
            }, function(err) {
                //some error
                console.log("Error: ", err);
                $("#preloader").css("display", "none");
            })
        }
```

Comment: Whats coming in console.log(vm.sections) ?
And what library are you using for dropdown?

Comment: i am getting the right data that is:
0
:
{sectionId: 1, section: "Survey Meta Data"}
1
:
{sectionId: 2, section: "Assessment"}
2
:
{sectionId: 3, section: "Income Survey Process"}
3
:
{sectionId: 4, section: "Appeal Process"}
4
:
{sectionId: 5, section: "Tax Authority"}
5
:
{sectionId: 6, section: "Contact Information"}

Comment: Whats the name of library your are using ?

Comment: angular-bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: Any link for that library you are using ?

Comment: use $timeout function and add your jquery lines there

Comment: https://bentorfs.github.io/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/

Comment: @Jenny what will happen then??

Comment: @KumailHussain it looks like before loading of data it make it multiselect. But using Timeout after loading of page it will make it multiselect.

Comment: @jenny let me try will let you know

Comment: @jenny thanks it worked:p

Comment: @KumailHussain u welcome.